# Max area of an island

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I took part in a coding competition and I got super close to the solving the following problem, but my code for some reason is not working out =(

Here is the link for the question:
https://leetcode.com/contest/leetcode-weekly-contest-53/problems/max-area-of-island/

My solution:

```
class Solution(object):
 def maxAreaOfIsland(self, grid):
    """
    :type grid: List[List[int]]
    :rtype: int
    """
    self.longest = 0
    self.count = 0
    row = len(grid)
    col = len(grid[0])
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            if grid[i][j] == 1:
                self.count += 1
                current = 1
                self.countIsland(i, j, current, grid)
    return self.longest
  def countIsland(self, k, z, current, grid):
    print(str(k) + "," + str(z) + "=" + str(current))
    grid[k][z] = -1
    if k > 0 and grid[k-1][z] == 1:
           return self.countIsland(k-1, z, current+1, grid)
    if k < (len(grid)-1) and grid[k+1][z] == 1:
           return self.countIsland(k+1, z, current+1, grid)
    if z > 0 and grid[k][z - 1] == 1:
           return self.countIsland(k, z-1, current+1, grid)
    if z < (len(grid[0])-1) and grid[k][z+1] == 1:
          return self.countIsland(k, z+1, current+1, grid)
    self.longest = max(self.longest, current)
    return current
```

I'm off by 1, I'm getting 5 instead of 6. If you try to run it in an IDE, my print statement will show that for the last call of the recursion the value current is being reinitialized which is not what I wanted. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your implementation correct? I mean at this line 'self.longest = max(self.longest, current)' , what if it reaches two near neighbours.

Comment: Please include the text of the problem in your question -- the link you provided requires registration.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is intuitive. We use DFS to expand the islands at every possible location. When an island cell is visited, we 'sink' it. Below is my Java implementation and passed all tests on Leetcode.

```
class Solution {
    private static final int[][] dirs = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}};

    public int maxAreaOfIsland(int[][] grid) {
        if (grid == null || grid.length == 0 || grid[0].length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
                    res = Math.max(res, dfs(grid, i, j));
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    private int dfs(int[][] grid, int x, int y) {
        if (grid[x][y] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        grid[x][y] = 0;
        int cnt = 1;
        for (int[] dir : dirs) {
            int nx = x + dir[0], ny = y + dir[1];
            if (nx >= 0 && nx < grid.length && ny >= 0 && ny < grid[0].length && grid[nx][ny] == 1) {
                cnt += dfs(grid, nx, ny);
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }
}
```